# How can I use an alternate UI in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

I am torn between using Evernote and Taskpaper for my todo list.

I love Taskpaper's UI - when I use a very simple markdown to identify tasks, contexts, and projects, the UI responds by formatting them as I would expect, but still retaining a plain text syntax.

Evernote, of course, is my system of record for such things.  My current workflow is to simply use my task list for a week, then archive it by adding it to the database.

My question is, is there a simpler alternative to this workflow?  Is there a way to simply use Taskpaper's UI with a note already in the Evernote database?

(For Clarification, TaskPaper is IOS only, and Evernote is running on my MAC, OS X 10.8.5)

Comment: What version of Evernote are you using?  I assume we are talking about a non-mobile version of Evernote?

Comment: Correct - I'm using it on my Mac, running 10.8.5

Comment: No, this is not possible. Just like Evernote doesn't have syntax recognition or markdown, you'd need to import what you want in as an attachment. What you can do is set up a personal wiki or something. Maybe check out [personal productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/)